# MySQLi Procedural Query Not Working

Tags: php, mysqli

This query is not updating the row in the database.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
mysqli_query("UPDATE `LOGIN` SET `HASH`='$hash' WHERE `USER`='$user'");
```

It simply does not update the hash in the row. I have checked the query in PMA and it seems to be running correctly. I have echo'ed out my $hash and $user variables on the screen to ensure they are valid, and they were. The mysqli_connect credentials are also correct... any input?

I have also tacked this onto mysqli_query and it just printed out "Error desc:" as I believe my server has errors off.

```
or die("Error desc: ".mysqli_error($link));
```

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: The table has around 3 records, so there's duplication is not issue here. Also, before anyone mentions it, I will be added a primary key to the table for each user and I will switch the mysqli to OO style once I figure out what's going on.

Comment: use [*bind_param*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and remove all the quotes and back-quotes from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alfasin wrote in the comments to use bind_param (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

It worked great. It is good for both OO and procedural.

Answer (score -1):

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `LOGIN` SET `HASH`='$hash' WHERE `USER`='$user'");